# Merging some list and dictionary data into one ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a few data structures returned from a `RandomForestClassifier()` and from encoding string data from a CSV. I am predicting the probability of certain crimes happening given some weather data. The model part works well but I'm a bit of a Python nooby and can't wrap my head around merging this data.

Here's a dumbed down version of what I have:

```
#this line is pseudo code
data = from_csv_file

label_dict = { 'Assault': 0, 'Robbery': 1 }

# index 0 of each cell in predictions is Assault, index 1 is Robbery
encoded_labels = [0, 1]

# Probabilities of crime being assault or robbery
predictions = [
               [0.4, 0.6], 
               [0.1, 0.9], 
               [0.8, 0.2], 
               ...
              ]
```

I'd like to add a new column to `data` for each crime label with the cell contents being the probability, e.g. new columns called `prob_Assault` and `prob_Robbery`. Eventually I'd like to add a boolean column (True/False) that shows if the prediction was correct or not.

How could I go about this? Using Python 3.10, pandas, numpy, and scikit-learn.

EDIT: Might be easier for some if you saw the important part of my actual code

```
# Training data X, Y
tr_y = tr['offence']
tr_x = tr.drop('offence', axis=1)

# Test X (what to predict)
test_x = test_data.drop('offence', axis=1)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=40)
fitted = clf.fit(tr_x, tr_y)
pred = clf.predict_proba(test_x)
encoded_labels = fitted.classes_

# I also have the encodings dictionary that shows the encodings for crime types
```

Comment: How do you want to check whether the probability was correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. What you need is to reformat the `predictions` from list to a numpy array and then access to its columns:

```py
import numpy as np
predictions = np.array(predictions)
data["prob_Assault"] = predictions[:,0]
data["prob_Robbery"] = predictions[:,1]
```

I am assuming that `data` is a pandas dataframe. I am not sure how you want to evaluate these probabilities, but you can use logical statements in the pandas as well:

```
data["prob_Assault"] == 0.8 # For example, 0.8 is the correct probability
```

The code above will return a Series of boolean such as:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
...
```

You can assign these values to the dataframe as a new column:

```py
data["check"] = data["prob_Assault"] == 0.8
```

Or even select the `True` rows of the dataframe:

```py
data[data["prob_Assault"] == 0.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your problem, but if not, that could be a solution :

- Create a dataframe with two columns : prob_Assault and prob_Robbery.

  predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns = ['prob_Assault', 'prob_Robbery'])
- Join that `predictions_df` to your data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).